# Appropriate to provide support for a commercial API on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags

I work for a company that sells a business intelligence tool that can be embedded and extended through a few APIs (.NET, JavaScript, and REST). Would it be appropriate to suggest to our clients that they post programming questions related to our APIs on Stack Overflow, so that there's publicly available & searchable support for them online?

If so, could I suggest that a new tag be added for the application? It would look like this:
[exago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exago)
*for programming questions relating to the embedded reporting and analytics application Exago BI*

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product-support for cases where support wasn't done correctly

Comment: Is your company going to invest the time and resources in having active users of Stack Overflow, and would they be capable of moderating the tag, too?